# How to declare variables in grafana trino data source

Tags: grafana, trino

When I run a query in Trino without a where clause, it takes a lot of time, with a where clause it takes a few seconds. Similarly, when I run a query without any where clause in Grafana, it seems that regardless of the time range, it loads all the data from the trino first, then in the panel, it shows the data of the desired time range, that’s why it takes a long time, but when I use the clause `where DATE_KEY between 20230829 and 20230904` in the query panel, the loading time of the panel is greatly reduced. But the problem is that this expression is fixed and I want the user to decide what data to see in the panel by selecting the time in the time range.

DATE_KEY column is a numeric or integer data type column, In order for the query to be dynamic I need to convert the `__from` and `__to` date ranges to be same format as DATE_KEY using one of the [date functions](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html).

```
declare @from = CAST(date_format(TIMESTAMP __from, ‘%Y-%m-%d’) as integer);
declare @to = CAST(date_format(TIMESTAMP __to, ‘%Y-%m-%d’) AS integer);
SELECT * FROM kimchi
WHERE DATE_KEY between @from and @to
GROUP BY DATE_KEY
```

but I am facing the following error:

```
error querying the database: trino: query failed (200 OK): “io.trino.sql.parser.ParsingException: line 1:1: mismatched input ‘declare’. Expecting: ‘ALTER’, ‘ANALYZE’, ‘CALL’, ‘COMMENT’, ‘COMMIT’, ‘CREATE’, ‘DEALLOCATE’, ‘DELETE’, ‘DENY’, ‘DESC’, ‘DESCRIBE’, ‘DROP’, ‘EXECUTE’, ‘EXPLAIN’, ‘GRANT’, ‘INSERT’, ‘MERGE’, ‘PREPARE’, ‘REFRESH’, ‘RESET’, ‘REVOKE’, ‘ROLLBACK’, ‘SET’, ‘SHOW’, ‘START’, ‘TRUNCATE’, ‘UPDATE’, ‘USE’, ”
```

Comment: WHERE DATE_KEY between ${__from:date:YYYYMMDD} and ${__to:date:YYYYMMDD}, That's right, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error you are getting, it looks like your data source doesn't expect `declare` instruction (I'm not even sure Trino supports it at all, but I'm no expert in Trino).

You can skip variable declaration and use inline casting with query like

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM kimchi 
WHERE DATE_KEY BETWEEN CAST(date_format(TIMESTAMP __from, ‘%Y%m%d’) as integer)
                   AND CAST(date_format(TIMESTAMP __to, ‘%Y%m%d’) AS integer) 
GROUP BY DATE_KEY
```

Note, I'm assuming based on description of your question that `DATE_KEY` contains dates in format `%Y%m%d`, and not the one you used in your attempts.

Alternatively, you can skip all the castings and use Grafana's [variable formatting](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/dashboards/variables/add-template-variables/#__from-and-__to):

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM kimchi 
WHERE DATE_KEY BETWEEN ${__from:date:YYYYMMDD} AND ${__to:date:YYYYMMDD} 
GROUP BY DATE_KEY
```